# Timer not running more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason when I run the below script for the first time, the timer doesn't activate again for a second time, any idea why?

```
 var timer = 0;
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#search').keypress(function() {
         if(timer == 0) { $('#sel').html('<iframe src="search.php?p=' + $('#search').val() + '"></iframe>');    }
         timer = 1;
         setTimeout('timer = 0;', 2000);        
      });
 });
```

Regards

Matthew

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` only runs once. You probably want `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#search').keypress(function() {
    if(timer == 0) { setTimeout('clearTimeout(this);timer = 0;', 2000); $('#sel').html('<iframe src="search.php?p=' + $('#search').val() + '"></iframe>');  }
    timer = 1;
});
```

Running the timer inside it fixed it well :)

Comment: `clearTimeout` is doing nothing for you here. First, you are running it when the timer has already expired. Second, you are passing it the wrong argument. You should pass it the timerID returned by `setTimeout`.